# Disable nividia card on Ubuntu 12.4 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu

please I would like to know how to disable my GPU card nividia and only enable my intel one?

Thanks

Comment: Should this be moved to askubuntu.com?

Comment: It is generic enough to stay here I think

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee). Also with Bumblebee you can run only certain (GPU-intensive) applications with the nVidia card while the rest of the system will run on the Intel power-optimized GPU.

Note that (as far as I know) you need the `nvidia` proprietary module for Bumblebee to work.